# Javascript Array range

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, native

I find my self using `_.range` a lot, and sometimes I don't want to drag with me `lodash` just for that reason.

What is the best way to do this without `lodash`?

My best solution is:

```
   export function range(n) {
     return new Array(n).fill(0).map((a, i) => i);
   }
```

Comment: I don't know if this counts as an answer, so I'm posting as a comment, but you can import [`lodash.range`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.range) as a standalone module without the rest of `lodash`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 return Array.from({length: n}, (_, i) => i);
```

...saves a few bytes.

Comment: Just a reminder, this is ES6+ only

Comment: Not only does this save bytes, it saves an iteration of the array compared to the approach in the question.